# pgadmin4 1.4 not starting on windows 7 enterprise

Tags: postgresql, pgadmin

When installing the latest release of pgadmin4 - 1.4 on a Windows 7 64 bit, I am not able to start it afterwards. It starts the first time autoamtically when the Installation process is finished, but afterwards I cannot start it with my "normal" Windows-user. It just appears the small pgadmin-Window, but nothing more happens, the main window never appears.
It does start with a user with Administration privileges. As I am working in an enterprise Environment normally I do not have administration privileges.
The log-file of the pg-admin is empty, and also there are no Windows Events logged. Has anybody a Suggestion, where I can start to search, where the Problem is?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Yeah. Same issue here. No solution so far.

Comment: I have tried pgadmin 4 1.5 and encountered the same problem. I have added the config_local.py file with the following Content: `SERVER_MODE = False
DEBUG = True
FILE_LOG_LEVEL = 10` Now I get many entries in the logfile, but I cannot encounter any error. The last line in the logfile is: `INFO werkzeug:  * Running on http://localhost:0/` I have sent a mail to the pgadmin-mailinglist, hoping the find some answers there.

Comment: The current vVersion on the pgadmin-site fixes the pProblem. I can now run pgadmin without admin privileges and without any problems.

Comment: What exactly did you do to fix this?

Comment: Download the current file from the pgadmin-Page (there is a new version from last friday) and install it. That solved my problem.

Comment: Could you provide a link for the download? Thanks.

Comment: You probably mean this: https://developer.pgadmin.org/~dpage/

Comment: Oh, yes. Sorry, that was the version I used. Sorry for the late answer, I have been out of the office.